# How do I access a property file outside classpath for a Spring/hibernate application deployed in DAP server?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a spring4/hibernate application.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.test")
public class AppConfig{
}

public class AppContext{
 public static AbstractApplicationContext getApplicationContext(){
  return new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
 }
}

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({"com.test.spring.config"})
@PropertySource(value={"classpath:application.properties"})
public class HibernateConfiguration{
 @Autowired
 private Environment environment;

 //rest of the code
}
```

We have deployed the application on a DAP server.

I want to access application.properties that is located on the DAP server (outside the application jar file).

I have removed the application.properties file from the application jar because the application seems to reference that by default.

How do I modify the above code to reference a property file on the deployed environment?

Comment: i dint think its possible

Comment: The properties are environment specific.

Comment: You can't.  You need to put those properties in JNDI or a database to access them.  You should have your database connections in a JNDI managed pool on the app server.   It's part of configuration.

Comment: What is a DAP server?!